# D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain failed (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, visual-studio, directx

So I'm creating a program that opens up another program when you hit a button, but I have no idea what I'm doing or how to go about solving this error:

```
   "D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain failed"
```

Here's the code:

```
    // When Launch Showroom button is pressed
    private void btn_LaunchShowroom_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        Process.Start( GameDir + "\\acShowroom.exe" );
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The machine that this error is occurring on, is it D3D11 compatible?

Comment: @Chris I'm pretty sure. I use the program I'm referring to with no problem. Only time the error occurs is when I'm trying to open it through this button in my application.

Comment: Hmmm. Weird. The application you're trying to launch, is it full-screen?

Comment: @chris it is fullscreen. I tried to run it in windowed mode like: Process.Start("game.exe", "-window"); but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If the application runs when you simply double click on the icon, the problem probably stems from your working directory not being set:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = GameDir;
startInfo.FileName = "acShowroom.exe"
Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

If you have any further problems, you can probably fix them by setting more of the ProcessStartInfo properties, which you can view [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).